# dynamically read xml element and value in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to read XML(whatever, i don't know it's structure, bcz i'm reading flie from server.), and i searched a lot on SO. but not found anything helpful.

1> i want to retrieve XML's node name, starting from root to end of file, child or child of child untill there's no child or sibling remaining.

2> in similar question, i found that they use tagname to retrieve value of that tag, so i want to pass that node name inside this to get value...

is it possible to do dynamically. or have to follow same structure as in previous questions like statically add tagname to retrieve value.

after doing this in java, i want to create executable jar, and want to use it in mirth.

---

**EDIT**
i want to find element and it's value such that, in first condition i'm looping my arraylist which i named `masterheader` which contain all tag name, and in second loop i'm going to find node name from xml, and and inside that two for loop i specified one condition, if both match, then it get node name and it store a value in , separated form, because i want to convert it in `csv`.

here, masterheader and childheader is `arraylist`. masterheader contain all header by default. and we gonna add nodename in `childheader`, nd if both match then we add value in result string.
for e.g. `masterheader = [employeename, employeesurname, fathername, mobile, salary]`
and in `childheader = [employeename, mobile, salary]` //this is based on xml parsing.

```
for(i=0;i<masterheader.size();i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<childheader.size();j++)
    {
         if((masterheader[i]).equals(childheader[j]))
        {
           //get the value of that node, + ","        
        }
        else
         {
                count++
         }
    }
if(count==childheader.size()){
 //add into result string +null+","  
}
}
```

Comment: Could you add a xml sample and explain how the xml would be different for other "dynamic tagnames"??? (or are you extracting some subset of information contained in the xml???)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("document.xml"));

    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            // do something with the current element
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
        }
    }
}
```

i think this will help

Comment: you are right, it giving you all node value..from starting to end `<starttag>` , but at the time of retrieving values, you get values for parents tag too :( , which print all child values as value of parent. nice try, but i want something better.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a StAX parser for this purpose.

#### XML sample `employees.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employees count="4">
    <employee>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstName>Jane</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <income>20000.0</income>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>3</id>
        <firstName>Alfred</firstName>
        <lastName>Pennyworth</lastName>
        <income>30000.0</income>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>4</id>
        <firstName>Tony</firstName>
        <lastName>Stark</lastName>
        <income>40000.0</income>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>42</id>
        <firstName>Foo</firstName>
        <lastName>Bar</lastName>
        <income>15.0</income>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

#### Java code

```
try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("employees.xml")) {
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);

    XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(stream);

    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        switch (reader.next()) {
            case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                System.out.println("Start " + reader.getName());
                for (int i = 0, count = reader.getAttributeCount(); i < count; i++) {
                    System.out.println(reader.getAttributeName(i) + "=" + reader.getAttributeValue(i));
                }
                break;
            case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                System.out.println("End " + reader.getName());
                break;
            case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
            case XMLStreamConstants.SPACE:
                String text = reader.getText();
                if (!text.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("text: " + text);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you could easily modify the `START_ELEMENT` case to compare the tag name to some value. (Probably you could ignore any other cases if you only want to check those elements.)

#### Output

```
Start employees
count=4
Start employee
Start id
text: 2
End id
Start firstName
text: Jane
End firstName
Start lastName
text: Doe
End lastName
Start income
text: 20000.0
End income
End employee
Start employee
Start id
text: 3
End id
Start firstName
text: Alfred
End firstName
Start lastName
text: Pennyworth
End lastName
Start income
text: 30000.0
End income
End employee
Start employee
Start id
text: 4
End id
Start firstName
text: Tony
End firstName
Start lastName
text: Stark
End lastName
Start income
text: 40000.0
End income
End employee
Start employee
Start id
text: 42
End id
Start firstName
text: Foo
End firstName
Start lastName
text: Bar
End lastName
Start income
text: 15.0
End income
End employee
End employees
```

Comment: can you update your answer with main and import statement too, because when i try to do, i'm getting error sign in `try{(InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("employees.xml")) {}` line, saying that `change project compliance and jdk to 1.7`.

Comment: @yash you're using a java version <7 ??? try-with-resources is unavailable then and you have to use `InputStream stream = ...; try { ...use stream... } finally { stream.close();}` instead...

Comment: after adding  `throws XMLStreamException, FileNotFoundException, IOException` in main method, it's working now, but there's one confusion. i'm going to edit question.

Comment: I have done some XML parsing using three ways, One was using StAX parser, the next was using an external java library called JDOM, this would be good. The third is always a best from my view, suing normal DocumentBuilderFactory and transformer java library, refer this link https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: I know about those possibilities. DOM+XPath could be a good option, but I recommended StAX, since this question started as *"I want to extract info from a tag with a given name"*. In this case DOM just has a unnecessary high memory use. It's still possible to make this work with StAX, but for this @yash would need to add some information about the xml structure to the question.