# Reading XML without Mapper classes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I need some help reg. parsing `xml` files. Currently, we are using `JAXB` to un-marshal the XML files to Java `POJOs`. We have created mapper `POJOs` from `xsd` using 'xjc' which have not changed since inception. But we are forecasting that the structure of the `xml` is going to change very often. So, we are thinking about looking for options other that `JAXB` since we cannot create mapper `POJOs` whenever the `xml` schema changes. We tried some parser like `DOM`, `SAX` but the performance is not good as `JAXB`.

**We are looking for,**

1. Dynamically deal with xml files of different structure without having pre-defined/created Java mapper classes
2. Schema validation is optional. Even if the schema validation fails we would like to parse and persist the data to the possible extend
3. Need to deal with **huge** files. `DOMParser` had performance issues with dealing these file

Comment: jaxb uses a parser such as dom, or sax (or maybe stax)  underneath, so i'd expect that jaxb will be slower than at least sax of stax.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy okay. The performance issue could be on my custom `event handlers` with `SAXParser`. I'm using `reflection` api there to generate dynamic objects.

Comment: make sure to use a Buffered stream/reader

Comment: JAXB is surprisingly fast given what it has to do, but you are right that it's a poor solution if the schema changes frequently. Of the generic object models (DOM, JDOM, DOM4J, AXIOM etc) my favourite is XOM.

Comment: Please don't use words like "huge". For some people huge means 100Mb, for others it means 100Gb. We're engineers, we like numbers.

Comment: @MichaelKay Okay, thank you for the advice. I was talking about files with size 150Mb.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("document.xml"));

    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            // do something with the current element
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
        }
    }
}
```

This might help you. Already this was answered in [dynamically read xml element and value in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636230/dynamically-read-xml-element-and-value-in-java)